# How to replace osx with Linux

Tags: partition, uefi, macos

I tried searching for this answer but the only one I would was from 2012 and surely things have changed since then. Anyway, I inherented an iMac from my Dad when he upgraded to a MacBook Air.

I'd like to know if I have to do anything special in order to completely replace osx with Linux. I use Linux on my current laptop and hope I can turn this iMac into a Linux-only computer.

I already know I'll have to set up an EFI partition, but do I need to do anything else? If I did just reformat the internal hdd, would it still be able to boot? Is there anything else I should know before undertaking this task. I really don't want to brick it, you know!

Thank you!

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask

Comment: Start by booting from a live Linux USB; Most installers are distributed in this way. That way you can take Linux for a test drive on the iMac hardware. Note: You can keep OSX, just in case, and dual-boot. You can shrink the OSX partition using it's built-in tools.